# ruby variable bash shell commands output assigned capistrano

Tags: ruby, bash, shell, capistrano

I am writing a task in capistrano 3.4 to print git version number in deployed code. I am able to print the code. Here i want to store the output   code in some variable. How i can store the output of shell command in ruby  variable. below is my task.

```
desc "version number"
task :set_current_version do
  on roles(:app) do
    execute "version=#{current_path}/REVISION ; cat $version "
  end
end
```

I need to store the cat $version output in variable. So i can refer this variable in another code.

Answer (score 1):

I got this solved this myself by using capture method below is example.

```
 on '1.example.com' do
   if test("[ -f somefile.txt ]")
     execute(:cp, 'somefile.txt', 'somewhere_else.txt')
   end
   ls_output = capture(:ls, '-l')
 end
```